# swift - rendering table view is slow

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm have a table view and I'm using the tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier to reuse the cells but still tableView is very slow.
and by slow, I mean it takes about 500 milliseconds to put 9 of my views in the tableView. and it's tested on apple A7 X64 processor so it must be pretty slower on older processors.
the reason that it's slow is because there are a few sub views and constraints.
but I've seen more complex tableCells with better performance, so there must be something I can do.
like caching a cell or something else??
any ideas?

sample code

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "ChatCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "ChatCell")
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ChatCell") as! ChatCell
        return cell
}
```

Comment: How do you know it's the constraints? If it's really them please show them.

Comment: No, I'm just guessing that constraints are slowing them down. how could one know?

Comment: Measure it with Instruments;)

Answer (score 3):

> the reason that it's slow is because there are a few sub views and constraints.

Personally, I don't suggest you use constraints in cell, especially when there're many subviews, it'll cost much CPU time and lead the scrolling lag. Instead, you can calculate manually based on cell frame.

And for more suggestion, i suggest you take time to read this post: [Simple Strategies for Smooth Animation on the iPhone](https://blog.twitter.com/2012/simple-strategies-for-smooth-animation-on-the-iphone).

Comment: wouldn't it be more optimized to let the constraint do the calculation? I can do it myself I just want to know if you know for sure that it's better if I did the positioning myself.

Comment: @MohsenShakiba it just helps us to handle auto layout related logic easier, but won't be optimised for performance (actually, it has a significant performance problem when there're lot nested subviews, but of course, it's fast enough for many cases), and u'd better to make cell's view hierarchy very simple. However, i'm not totally sure whether it's indeed the reason that leads ur tableview lag, but what i suggested here is that only use auto layout when u need, like for dynamic UI that need to resized frequently. :)

Answer (score 1):

The call to `registerNib` is normally done only once in `viewDidLoad`, not every time you are asked for a cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Not sure how slow that call is, but it might be the reason for your slow response.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using effects (like shadow or round corners or etc) or having heavy calculations on UI

**Edit: Code Sample added**

```
//Add in your init func
tblView.registerClass(MSCustomVerticalListCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: NSStringFromClass(MSCustomVerticalListCell))

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     let cell = tblView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(NSStringFromClass(MSCustomVerticalListCell), forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MSCustomVerticalListCell
     //add data binding
     cell.item = dataSource[indexPath.row]
     return cell
}
```

Your data binding class (Data Model):

```
class MSC_VCItem
{
    var Title:String!
    var Action:String!
    var SubTitle:String!
    var Icon:String!

    init(title:String!,subTitle:String!,icon:String!,action:String!)
    {
        self.Title = title
        self.SubTitle = subTitle
        self.Icon = icon
        self.Action = action
    }
}
```

And Finally you custom table cell:

```
class MSCustomVerticalListCell : UITableViewCell {
    let padding = 5
    let imageWidth = 50
    var customImageView: UIImageView!
    var customTitleLabel: UILabel!
    var customSubtitleLabel: UILabel!
    var item: MSC_VCItem? {
        didSet {
            if let it = item {
                customTitleLabel.text = it.Title
                customSubtitleLabel.text = it.SubTitle
                UIImage.loadFromCacheOrURL(it.Icon, callback: { (image: UIImage) -> () in
                    self.customImageView.image = image
                })
                setNeedsLayout()
            }
        }
    }

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

        customTitleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectZero)
        self.addSubview(customTitleLabel)

        customSubtitleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectZero)
        contentView.addSubview(customSubtitleLabel)

        customImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectZero)
        customImageView.image = UIImage(named: "default")
        contentView.addSubview(customImageView)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        //Write your UI here like bg color or text color
    }
}
```

Comment: Does loaded your image sync or Async?

Comment: actually I don't do image loading, because it would be even slower.